# Record-triggered Flow Email Message

Tags: email, visual-workflow

I have a record-triggerd Flow that runs on Create and Update of Email Message.

However, when I just open an email message (that's already been received weeks ago) the flow triggers for some reason. Are there entry criteria I should be setting on the flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a known issue for this that came about after the introduction of [Enable Unread/Read on Compact Case Feed](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_cases_unread_read_feed_items.htm&type=5&release=222) in Winter '20.

[EmailMessage trigger gets invoked when viewing the message in feeditem](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001q6joQAA)

Interestingly, this has been [requested as a feature](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdjgTUAR/fire-a-update-trigger-after-emailmessage-system-update) for a while - but, this is only happening when viewing the email message through the feed. It's actually firing when you click on the info icon (or the expand icon) in the screenshot below (apex trigger and record-triggered flows).

[image]

You can workaround this by adding an entry condition in your record-triggered flow to not fire when `Status` changes on [EmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) since that is the update that is occuring - changing from `0`*(New)* to `1`/*(Read)*.

[image]

Otherwise, you could set it to only run on create if you don't actually need the update condition as it's not clear, from your question, if you are doing anything in that scenario.